# Conditionally rendered React components not resetting state

Tags: reactjs

I have a `switch` statement that conditionally renders a component with certain props, depending on the state of the parent component, like so:

```
switch(props.count) {
  case 1:
    return ( <MyComponent onButtonClick={props.handler1} onNextClick={props.next} /> );
  case 2:
    return ( <MyComponent onButtonClick={props.handler2} onNextClick={props.next} /> );
  ...
}
```

In each component, I set a boolean value in `this.state` which should initially be false. When a certain handler method is called, `props.count` should update in the parent element, and the component defined under the next case should render. This works, however the new component does not get the default flag value (false), but instead keeps the state the previous component had. Why does this happen? Since the props change from one case to another, isn't the component being reconstructed?

MyComponent:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    flag: false,
  }
  this.myHandler = this.myHandler.bind(this);
}

myHandler() {
  this.setState({
    flag: true,
  });
  this.props.onButtonClick();
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={this.myHandler} disabled={flag} />
      <Button onClick={props.next} disabled={!flag} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  I have had this same issue and was forced to use this lifecyclemethod.  You should check the incoming props and prevprops with a console.log.  See if they are updated at all, and if so, change the state to match the new update.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props!== prevProps) {
    //set state here;
  }
}
```